# Converting JSON response into a GeoJSON layer in my Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, json

I need to convert a JSON response from Mapquest elevation API into a GeoJSON layer in my Leaflet map.

```
var ele = $.getJSON('http://open.mapquestapi.com/elevation/v1/profile?key=<API_KEY>&shapeFormat=raw&latLngCollection='+profile);
```

this is a sample of JSON reponse:

```
{
   "shapePoints":[
      39.74012,
      -104.9849,
      39.7995,
      -105.7237,
      39.6404,
      -106.3736
   ],
   "elevationProfile":[
      {
         "distance":0,
         "height":1616
      },
      {
         "distance":63.5583,
         "height":3910
      },
      {
         "distance":121.9561,
         "height":2501
      }
   ],
   "info":{
      "copyright":{
         "text":"© 2018 MapQuest, Inc.",
         "imageUrl":"http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
         "imageAltText":"© 2018 MapQuest, Inc."
      },
      "statuscode":0,
      "messages":[

      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've loaded the response you can convert the `shapePoints` and `elevationProfile` arrays to an array of coordinate points that can be inserted in a blank GeoJSON feature object and loaded

```
// You can do it with a functional approach:
// Use Array.filter() to sort the alternating points to lats and lngs,
// then use Array.map() to extract the elevations
// and 'zip' the three arrays in one array of lng/lat/elev (x/y/z!) arrays
var lats = shapePoints.filter(function(e, i) {return i % 2 === 0;});
var lngs = shapePoints.filter(function(e, i) {return i % 2 != 0;});
var elevs = elevationProfile.map(function(e, i) {return e.height;});
var lnglats = lngs.map(function(e, i) {return [e, lats[i], elevs[i]];});

// or the more traditional way:
var lnglats = [];
for (var i=0; i<shapePoints.length; i=i+2) {
    lnglats.push([shapePoints[i+1], shapePoints[i], elevationProfile[i/2].height]);
}

geojson = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": lnglats
    }
};

L.geoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks, i just need to add "height" value as well to geometry.coordinates in the polyline.

Comment: OK, updated to pull the elevations

Comment: it returns NAN instead of Z/elevation on the output GeoJSON.

Comment: Are you using the first example? I had a `filter` instead of `map` to extract the elevations

Comment: It works now, but i need to add that polyline on the map as a GeoJSON layer, in order to implement elevation profile chart on it and calculate some values about elevations.

Comment: See update to use GeoJSON